# Reduce the height of the table head and stretch to the left and right of margin

Tags: longtable

This is my table:

[image]

And i want this table has format like this (the double `hline` after title should be there i forgot to add and there is no vertical line also):

[image]

Btw, i'm using repeated table head and trying to use `p{x cm}` but error message appears. It  said `Package array error bla bla bla`.
Please help me. Thanks!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace,amsmath,times,array,caption,lipsum,longtable}
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\sloppy
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
\linespread{1.5}
\begin{document}
        \begin{center}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \begin{longtable}{cl}
            \caption{ODE Examples}\\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\centering \textbf{ODE}}
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\centering \textbf{Classification}}\\
            \hline \hline
            \endfirsthead
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\centering \textbf{ODE}}
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\centering \textbf{Classification}}\\
            \hline \hline
            \endhead 
            $\dfrac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} = y+x$ & First Order ODE \\
            \hline
            $\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d} x^2}\right)^2 + 2\dfrac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} -3y = 0$ & Second order ODE \\
            \hline
        \end{longtable}
    \end{center}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: something like the answer below -- `0.5\textwidth` is added in the definition of the table to spread  each of the  two columns to 50 percent of the textwidth -- `makecell` package and `cellgape` is used to give a gap between the row line and the maths content

Comment: Remove the center environment around the longtable.

Comment: @user516076 -- centering of the first column added also -- forgot to do that

Comment: You already load the cellspace package. Why don't you use this package to adjust the height of your table rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace,amsmath,times,array,caption,lipsum,longtable}
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\sloppy
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
{ \setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells%
        \begin{longtable}{p{0.5\textwidth}|p{0.5\textwidth}}
            \caption{ODE Examples}\\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{ODE}}
            & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textbf{Classification}}\\
            \hline \hline
            \endfirsthead
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ODE}}
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Classification}}\\
            \hline \hline
            \endhead 
            $\dfrac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} = y+x$ & First Order ODE \\
            \hline
            $\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d} x^2}\right)^2 + 2\dfrac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} -3y = 0$ & Second order ODE \\
            \hline
        \end{longtable}
}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

**edit -- for the centering of the first column contents**

added --    `\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace,amsmath,times,array,caption,lipsum,longtable}
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\sloppy
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
    { \setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells%
        \begin{longtable}{P{0.5\textwidth}|p{0.5\textwidth}}
            \caption{ODE Examples}\\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{ODE}}
            & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textbf{Classification}}\\
            \hline \hline
            \endfirsthead
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ODE}}
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Classification}}\\
            \hline \hline
            \endhead 
            $\dfrac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} = y+x$ & First Order ODE \\
            \hline
            $\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d} x^2}\right)^2 + 2\dfrac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} -3y = 0$ & Second order ODE \\
            \hline
        \end{longtable}
    }
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your table will be wider than the textwidth since you did not take into account the value of tabcolsep that is added to either side of the table nor the width of the vertical line. You can also see this in the screenshot you added. Notice how the horizontal lines are wider than the text block below the table.

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce the height of the header by adding negative vertical space. I added  new column types for better control of the width of the columns, if needed.

The rules in the `booktabs` package also vertically expand cells for a cleaner appearance.

[image: xy]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace,amsmath,times,array,caption,lipsum,longtable}
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\sloppy
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1\textwidth}}

\linespread{1.5}
\begin{document}    

%\begin{center}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{longtable}{Y{0.5}P{0.25}}% <<< set the columns widths
        \caption{ODE Examples}\\
        \toprule \\ [-45pt]
            \textbf{ODE}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Classification}\\ [-5pt]
        \midrule\midrule 
        \endfirsthead
        \toprule \\ [-45pt]
            \textbf{ODE}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Classification}\\ [-5pt]
        \midrule\midrule 
        \endhead        
        $\dfrac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} = y+x$ &  {First Order ODE}\\
        \midrule
        $\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d} x^2}\right)^2 + 2\dfrac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} -3y = 0$ & {Second order ODE} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
%\end{center}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```